# How to run service class in background continuously Even app crash (swipe the app to kill)

Tags: java, android, arraylist, service

In my application i am using service class and `activity` class,where i am updating array list values for every minute in service class and showing it in activity class using callback method in service class.
 I am updating array list values in `onStartCommand()` , return `Service.START_NOT_STICKY`; and its working fine but when i killing the application by swiping aside application is starting form starting stage(losing previous data) and service is stopping at certain time.

For that i tried to use return `Service.START_STICKY`, when i used START_STICKY its working fine with continuously update in service class.but when i killing the application by swiping aside, showing error in callback method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is not the proper one as you won't be able to run service in the background for an infinite time in Android Oreo. You should consider using [Firebase Job Dispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android) which can be used to run a block of code after regular intervals.